# Is is possible to send a CDP data stream or segment to a Qlik?

Tags: api, salesforce-cdp, cdp

I am looking to pull information directly from Salesforce CDP to Qlik.

The only documentation I can find regarding connecting Salesforce to Qlik is [this](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/connectors/Subsystems/Salesforce_Connector_help/Content/Connectors_Salesforce/Introduction/Salesforce-connector.htm).
https://help.qlik.com/en-US/connectors/Subsystems/Salesforce_Connector_help/Content/Connectors_Salesforce/Introduction/Salesforce-connector.htm

Is it possible to do a direct CDP to Qlik connection? OR would the only option at this time be to send a segment to SFMC then have Qlik pickup a data extract of that segment?

Comment: The answer is no